# Encryption and decryption - code problems

Tags: android, encryption

Hi I have this code beneath (code 1) which should reverse the effect of another code (code 2), but it doesnt work properly in either of the codes. Can someone help me with this? :)

Code 2 takes a text and takes each letter, times it with a number and finds the rest with modulus 29 of it. This new number is then the encrypted letter. I would then like to reverse this with code 1.

my alphabet = a, b, c, ..., æ, ø, å = 29 letters

An example "you" with the factors 1, 2 and 3 becomes

(25*1)%29 = 25

(15*2)%29 = 1

(21*3)%29 = 5

"yae"

Then to reverse it i take the new letter, divide it by the factor and check if is a number without decimals. If it isnt then i add 29 to the lettervalue and start over.

example again with 1, 2 and 3

"yae"

(25/1)%29 = 25

(1/2)%29 = 0,5 then add 29

(30/2)%29 = 15

(5/3)%29 = 1,66 then add 29

(34/3)%29 = 11,33 then add 29

(63/3)%29 = 21

"you"

code 1

```
String initialString = yourString.getText().toString();
        char[] chars = initialString.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 1; i <= chars.length; i++) {
            if (chars[i-1] == ' '){
                continue;   
            }
            C = Integer.valueOf(faktorA);
            if ( i%2 ==0 ) C = Integer.valueOf(faktorB);
            if ( i%3 ==0 ) C = Integer.valueOf(faktorE);

            chars[i-1] = characters.get((characters.indexOf(chars[i-1]) / C)%29);

            if(chars[i-1]%1 != 0){
                chars[i-1] = (char) (chars[i-1] * C + 29);
                chars[i-1] = characters.get((characters.indexOf(chars[i-1]) / C)%29);
            }
        }
```

code 2

```
    String initialString = yourString.getText().toString();
        char[] chars = initialString.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 1; i <= chars.length; i++) {
            if (chars[i-1] == ' '){
                continue;   
            }
            C = Integer.valueOf(faktorA);
            if ( i%2 ==0 ) C = Integer.valueOf(faktorB);
            if ( i%3 ==0 ) C = Integer.valueOf(faktorE);

            chars[i-1] = characters.get((characters.indexOf(chars[i-1]) * C)%29);
        }
```

Comment: where is problem then?

Comment: When I use the code the result of code 2 is "you" --> "yåc" and the result of code 1 "yae" --> "yab"

Comment: it should be "you" --> "yae" and "yae" --> "you" as i said above

Comment: There are multiple problems with the code. Hint for one: `if(chars[i-1]%1 != 0)` when you expect the modulus of division of an integer by one to be non-zero?

Comment: It should check if the decrypted char had decimals and if it had decimals then it should add 29 to the encrypted char which we started with and try over until it found a number without decimals.

Comment: isnt that what it does? btw im a bit new to programming therefore i ask why it doesnt work :/

Comment: Integers and division ... 2 / 2 = 1 .... 1 / 2 = 0 ... in other words ... if you devide integers the result will allways be an integer... no fractions ... if you want fractions try float or double

Comment: if(chars[i-1]%1 != 0) I use modulus 1 on the char number... i dont devide the char number with 1

Comment: I've voted to close as "too localized". This question is focussed on debugging a piece of code that implements a non-standard cryptographic algorithm. I'm not sure it will be helpful for future readers.